# wrong result in MongoDB mapreduce function?

Tags: mongodb

I have Collection "cars" from that want to get count of certified cars as trueCount and flaseCount where certified is boolean.

am issuing the following mapreduce query

map:-

```
function() { for (var idx = 0; idx < this.cars.length; idx++) {
                           var key = this.cars[idx].carName;
                           var value = {
                               count : 1, 
                               certifiedCheck : this.cars[idx].certified
                           };
                           emit(key, value);
                       } }
```

reduce:-

```
function(key, values) { 
    certifiedCount = { trueCount: 0, falseCount: 0 };
    values.forEach(function(value) {
            if ( value.certifiedCheck )
                certifiedCount.trueCount += value.count;
            else 
                certifiedCount.falseCount += value.count;
       });      
return certifiedCount;
```

query:

```
{ "type": "cars" }
```

getting the following result :

```
{ "id" : "carName" , "value" : { "true" : 277.0 , "false" : NaN}};
```

even though I have 457 documents in the collection.

Please someone help me here to fix this issue.

Thanks in advance

Comment: I think it is rather recommended to use the aggregation framework. Would you consider doing this with the aggregation framework in your case? And which MongoDB version are you using?

Comment: And on a side note, could you let us know the important parts of the car document structure?

Answer (score 0):

You mixed up your map-reduce: to reduce to two keys "true" and "false" you need to emit these as keys. Then, the reducer will run per key.

As pseudo code:

```
map:

for each car
    evaluate whether it should be true or false
    key = (true/false)
    emit(key, { count : 1 })

reduce:

(input is true/false as key, array of count-documents as value)

for each value-document
    sum up the count
return key, sum
```

This should yields two documents with true / false as key and the respective sum as value.

Answer (score 0):

You should consider using the **[aggregation framework](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/aggregation/)** for running the aggregation since it achieves the same result albeit faster than MapReduce as aggregation runs natively in the server (C++), MapReduce spawns separate javascript thread(s) to run JS code.

Thus said, if you run the following aggregation pipeline which uses the **[`$cond`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/cond/#exp._S_cond)** operator to evaluate the counts based on the logic in the field expression, you will get a similar result:

*Because you haven't showed your collection schema, I've assumed the following sample documents with a `cars` field as array having seen in your mapReduce you are doing a for loop on the `cars` property:*

**Populate test collection**

```
db.collection.insert([
    { _id: 1, cars: [ { model: "A", certified: true }, { model: "B", certified: true } ] },
    { _id: 2, cars: [ { model: "A", certified: false }, { model: "B", certified: true } ] },
    { _id: 3, cars: [ { model: "A", certified: true }, { model: "B", certified: false } ] },
    { _id: 4, cars: [ { model: "A", certified: true }, { model: "B", certified: false } ] },
    { _id: 5, cars: [ { model: "A", certified: true }, { model: "B", certified: true } ] }
])
```

**Run aggregation operation**

```
db.collection.aggregate([
    { "$unwind": "$cars" },
    {
        "$group": {
            "_id": "$cars.model",
            "trueCount": {
                "$sum": {
                    "$cond": [ "$cars.certified", 1, 0 ]
                }
            },
            "falseCount": {
                "$sum": {
                    "$cond": [ "$cars.certified", 0, 1 ]
                }
            }
        }
    }
])
```

**Result:**

```
/* 1 */
{
    "_id" : "A",
    "trueCount" : 4,
    "falseCount" : 1
}

/* 2 */
{
    "_id" : "B",
    "trueCount" : 3,
    "falseCount" : 2
}
```